# Rubyでseleniumを使ってremoteで接続する際にNet::ReadTimeoutになる

Tags: ruby, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

現在、DockerCompose上のRubyでseleniumを使って、別サーバにchromeを使いたいのですがうまく動作しません。
以下に各種コードとエラー内容を書かせていただきます。

- DockerCompose.yml

```yml
version: "3"
services:
  rails:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RailsDockerFile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    tty: true
  chrome:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:4.0.0-beta-3-20210426
    container_name: chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900
      - 7900:7900
```

- RailsDocker内のRuby Code

```rb
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :remote, url: 'http://chrome:4444', desired_capabilities: :chrome
```

- Error内容

```sh
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
```

なぜこのようなエラーになるのでしょうか？
ご回答お待ちしております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

タイムアウトを180秒に設定すれば、接続できるようになりました。